# How to refactor a step-wise code?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Consider a code sample.

1. Is this some pattern which I am not aware of ?
2. How to clean this clutter ?

   ```
   int func1val = func1();
   boolean val = checkIfTrue(func1val);
   if (val) {
       int func2val = func2();
       val = checkIfTrue(func2val);
       if (val) {
           int func3val = func3();
           val = checkIfTrue(func3val);
       }
   }

   if (val) {
   // print func1val, func2val, func3val, 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're printing out those three values if and only if `checkIfTrue` returns true for all three. Barring some implementation detail of `checkIfTrue`, couldn't you do something like

```
int func1val = 0, func2val = 0, func3val = 0; // any value here
if (checkIfTrue(func1val = func1()) && checkIfTrue(func2val = func2()) && checkIfTrue(func3val = func3())) {
    // print func1val, func2val, func3val
}
```

To be fair, something like

```
int func1val = func1();
if (checkIfTrue(func1val)) {
    int func2val = func2();
    if (checkIfTrue(func2val)) {
        int func3val = func3();
        if (checkIfTrue(func3val)) {
            // print func1val, func2val, func3val
        }
    }
}
```

ought to do the same thing, and may be more readable depending on the actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

How to clean it is with mid-method returns.

```
int func1val = func1();
boolean val = checkIfTrue(func1val);
if (!val) return;
int func2val = func2();
val = checkIfTrue(func2val);
if (!val) return;
int func3val = func3();
val = checkIfTrue(func3val);
if (!val) return;

// print func1val, func2val, func3val,
```

And then you don't even need val; just inline each occurrence:

```
int func1val = func1();
if (!checkIfTrue(func1val)) return;
int func2val = func2();
if (!checkIfTrue(func2val)) return;
int func3val = func3();
if (!checkIfTrue(func3val)) return;

// print func1val, func2val, func3val,
```